# Почему-то у программа никак не реагирует на прикасание к картинке. В чём может быть проблема?

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private ViewGroup mMoveLayout;
    private int mX;
    private int mY;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mMoveLayout =  (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.move);
        mImageView = new ImageView(this);
        mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardsa1);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
        mImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
       mImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
               final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
               final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
               switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                       mX = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                       mY = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                       break;
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                       layoutParams.leftMargin = X - mX;
                       layoutParams.topMargin = Y - mY;
                       layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                       layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                       v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                       break;
               }
               return true;
           }
       });
    }

}
```

Comment: Вы же создаете ImageView и не добавляете его в контейнер addView , он у вас просто создался как объект и был стерт при выходе из onCreate

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы ваш виджет реагировал на нажатия, добавьте в xml разметке вашей активности к данному виджету такие свойства ([вопрос enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326601/android-imageview-on-click)):

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

так же для обработки нажатий можно использовать не только `setOnTouchListener`, но и `setOnClickListener`:

```
imgview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
});
```

### UPDATE

Я только заметил что вы создаете виджет программно, попробуйте установить ему такой параметр:

```
imgview.setClickable(true);
```

и так можно попробовать:

```
imgview.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

и еще так:

```
imgview.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Что-то не помогает

Comment: Не помогли строки android:clickable и android:focusable. Я как раз таки через консоль и понял что не работает

Comment: Параметры в xml? Я не очень понял

Comment: Всё так же осталось

Comment: Эх, не помогло. Похоже я уже безнадёжен)

Comment: Ну что ж в любом случае большое спасибо за уделённое время

Comment: а какая причина создания виджета программно? можно ведь взять с макета

Comment: и еще вопрос - куда вы добавляете ваш виджет, у вас нету строки someView.addView(image); так что может в это причина?